# Windows.Form ComboBox Cannot set the SelectedValue Property of Unbound Control

Tags: c#, combobox

I cannot set the default combobox selected value for an unbound combobox. Here is my code:

```
         System.Console.WriteLine("Current Tag Org Id = " + CurrentTag.Org.OrgId);
         ddlRUC.SelectedValue = CurrentTag.Org.OrgId;
         System.Console.WriteLine("ddlRUC selected value = " + ddlRUC.SelectedValue);
```

Here is the output:
Current Tag Org Id = 285
ddlRUC selected value =

Note that ddlRUC.SelectedValue has not been set to 285. Does the datasource need to be bound in order to use the SelectedValue property? If so, how do I set the default item shown in a combobox that is not bound?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SelectedValue property will only work for a databound listbox.  If you can create your list items in a List<>, you can then bind the list to the control and SelectedValue will work as you would like.

Answer (score 13):

A combobox (like a Listbox) has 2 mechanisms for dealing with the selection. Either:

1. You assign a List to the DataSource
   property and set the ValueMember and
   DisplayMember to the names of
   properties of items of that list. Or,
2. You fill the Items property with
   objects of your choice, the `ToString()`
   will be displayed.

In scenario 1) you can use SelectedValue to get/set the selection based on the ValueMember.

in scenario 2) you use SelectedItem property instead of SelectedValue

So the question is, how do you fill the Items?

Comment: To some confusion, the DisplayMember property works well together with "manually added" items in the ListControls, unlike the ValueMember property that is active only together with databinding.

Comment: OK, didn't know that. And there's also a FormatString and a Format event.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this problem, wasting precious time because the value in my list was a different int type than the value I was trying to assign to the SelectedValue e.g. int32 vs int16.  The thing that will drive you crazy is that there's no compile error or run time exception thrown.  It just doesn't work.  Get the int types to match and it works great!  Note that it is essential for the combobox to be bound.

Comment: Thank you Frank!  After days of searching and sorting through megabytes of dead ends and misinterpretations, someone finally, finally, addresses the problem that cannot be searched since the failure is silent!  And this is the one!  And from a guy with 21 prestige points to boot.  You've got at least 121 prestige points in my book!  lol.

Comment: Amen dude, If I ever run into you, dinner and beer is on me

Answer (score 0):

Does your unbound ComboBox have 286 items in it? Otherwise that id won't mean anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but the ComboBox either has to have Items (I believe it has .Items, just like a ListBox) or it has to be bound to a datasource before there can be a default item.

Answer (score 0):

Do the items in your combobox have values?  You could use Items.FindByText(string text) or Items.FindByValue(string value) to return the ListItem you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) states that the property will return "an object containing the value of the member of the data source specified by the ValueMember property". The [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) property documentation states that it represents the name of an object property in the collection that is assigned to the DataSource property.

So yes, ValueMember works only together with a databound data source.