# How to bind Enum to ComboBox in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagrid

I found this on Stack Overflow, but no where I could get an answer.

I want to bind a ComboBox of a data grid to a `property of a class` which returns [one of the ] Enum Value.

```
MyEnum
{
    [StringValue("SomeVal")]
    SomeVal,
    [StringValue("AnotherVal")]
    AnotherVal,
    [StringValue("OneMoreVal")]
    OneMoreVal
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyEnum A_Value
    {
        return whatever; // whatever is MyEnum type
    }
}
```

Now I made a Data grid column having combo box and there I need to bind a property

```
myCombo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)); 
myCombo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", myDataSource, bindingPath + ".A_Value");
```

When I run this code, it fails with error

> "Cannot set a value to a combo box without a ValueMember"

Then I add below line

```
myCombo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

It does not fail this time, but no selected value is set.
**Can someone help me out with the problem ?**

---

What I referred:

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/binding-an-enum-to-a-combobox/
- [Binding an enum to a WinForms combo box, and then setting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906899/binding-an-enum-to-a-winforms-combo-box-and-then-setting-it)
- [How to bind an enumeration to combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638639/how-to-bind-an-enumeration-to-combobox)
- [adding enum values to a simple combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040872/adding-enum-values-to-a-simple-combobox)

Comment: You've tagged as WPF, but this looks like WinForms and some fo the links are for WinForms.  Which is it?

Comment: @CharlesMager Apologies, WinForms it is

Comment: this helped me --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983350/windows-form-combobox-cannot-set-the-selectedvalue-property-of-unbound-control

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `myDataSource` is supposed to be an implementation of `MyClass`... Here's an example of how to databind it. It's a little verbose but maybe someone can improve upon it.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private MyClass one;
    private Label label1;
    private ComboBox comboBox1;
    private FlowLayoutPanel panel;
    private Button btn1;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        one = new MyClass();
        panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        label1 = new Label();
        comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
        btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Text = "Click to change Property";
        btn1.Click += (sender, args) => { one.A_Value = MyEnum.BtnVal; }; // to test binding to the property

        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
        panel.Controls.Add(label1);
        panel.Controls.Add(btn1);

        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            one.A_Value = (MyEnum)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem; // update the object when the ComboBox is changed
        };

        comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem",one,"A_Value"); // update the ComboBox if the Property is changed by something else
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text",one,"A_Value"); // to show that changes happen to the property and not just the ComboBox
    }



}

public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("SomeVal")]
    SomeVal,
    [Description("AnotherVal")]
    AnotherVal,
    [Description("OneMoreVal")]
    OneMoreVal,
    [Description("ButtonClickedValue")]
    BtnVal
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyEnum whatever;

    public MyEnum A_Value
    {
        get { return whatever; } 
        set { whatever = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("A_Value"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Comment: thanks for good explanation. this helped me --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983350/windows-form-combobox-cannot-set-the-selectedvalue-property-of-unbound-control

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your `datagridview` is binded to list of `MyClass`.
If you using `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` type, then use property `DatPropertyName`.

```vb
'Use property name of your class to where combobox will be binding
myCombo.DataPropertyName = "A_Value"
```

Then after `myCombo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));`
if value of `instanceOf MyClass.A_Value` will be in the DataSource of combobox
it be shown.

**Update**
If you using normal `ComboBox` control, then you need specify `ValueMember` property

```
myCombo.ValueMember = "A_Value";
```

Check name of the property is right. Because in you question it is wrong.

Comment: I could not find any property as `DataPropertyName` as mine is a DataGrid and not `DataGridView`

Comment: `Winfroms` haven't control `DataGrid`. Unless you using some third part solution...

Comment: this helped me --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983350/windows-form-combobox-cannot-set-the-selectedvalue-property-of-unbound-control